# Loading CSS3 when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML code. I have applied some animations to the logo using CSS3 and it's working as I wanted. Now the animation works when we hover on the logo. I want the animation to work automatically when the page loads.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>After Quote</title>
<style type="text/css">
.container {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #1180AE;
height: 340px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 50px;
width: 215px;
background: url(container.jpg) no-repeat;
}
.content {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 8px;
height: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 115px;
width: 194px;
}
.logo:hover {
border-radius: 50%;
transform: rotate(720deg);
}
.logo {
height: 80px;
margin: 0 auto;
transition: all 1s ease 0s;
width: 80px;
}
.logo img {
border-radius: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="logo"> <a href="#"> <img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" /></a> </div>
    <!--logo--> 
  </div>
  <!--content--> 
</div>
<!--container-->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways how you can achieve this:

The first one is to add a class to the logo after pageload with JavaScript. You need to do this, because CSS **transitions** only react on changes like classlist changes, hover etc., but can not start by itself.

The second way is to use CSS **keyframe animations**, which I believe is more what you want. You can learn about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations

Comment: Can we implement it using jquery?

Comment: Yes you can also use jQuery. For example: Add `$('.logo').addClass('animated');` in a `<script>` tag in the footer of the site and then change the CSS selector `.logo:hover` to `.logo.animated`.

Answer (score 0):

It won't unless you use @keyframes CSS animations. you can use like mentioned below..

and use `animation-rotate` class in your `img` tag. Here is the **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/kiganexa/1/)**.

```
.animation-rotate {
    margin:auto;
    -webkit-animation:coinflip 2s infinite linear;
    animation:coinflip 2s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation:coinflip 2s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes coinflip {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:rotateY(-1deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes coinflip {
    0% {
        -moz-transform:rotateY(-1deg);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes coinflip {
    0% {
        transform:rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform:rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@-webkit-keyframes anm {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    25% {-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);}
    50% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
    75% {-webkit-transform: rotate(540deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);}
}
@keyframes anm {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    25% {transform: rotate(180deg);}
    50% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
    75% {transform: rotate(540deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(720deg);}
}
.logo img {
height: 80px;
border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-animation: anm 1s;
animation: anm 1s;
}
.logo img:hover {
border-radius: 50%;
transition: all 1s ease 0s;
-webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);
transform: rotate(720deg);
}
```